# ssrs repeat column

Tags: reporting-services

I was wondering if its possible/how to make a ssrs report
so that a column will increment down the page until the end and then continue in the next column

```
Time    Weight Size   CONTINUED   

1:00    110    14    4:00    113    10

2:00    114    16    5:00    115    13

3:00    112    11    6:00    117    15
```

End of page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the report **Body** properties, you can set **Columns** to 2 in the **layout** properties. This will cause your page to wrap around.

---update based on your comments ---

ok so what you want is effectively a matrix. You will need to modify your query so that it returns your row number, let's call this item_id. Then you will create a column group in your matrix grouping on cint(item_id / 15) if you want to wrap every 15 items, right above your column headers.

So your grouping on the matrix would look like this (you can set the row group to hidden, or make it small):

```
                        col_group1 ("=cint(item_id /15)")
                        col_group2 ("=column_header")
row_group ("=item_id")  detail ("=value")
```

Your result set would have to be returned unpivoted. So you would have to stack your results into format like this:

```
item_id  column_header  value 
   1         Time        1:00      
   1         Weight      120     
   1         Size        12      
   1         Time        3:00      
   1         Weight      110      
   1         Size        13
```

This way you will have the top column group each 15 of your results into adjacent columns

Hope this helps.

Comment: That only works for the entire report. It doesnt work for a section of the report for example if I have a long header section or if I have a lot of information in a group section or a graph in a group section, and I only want the details section to repeat its columns????

Comment: Also, that only works for the print setting not in the normal report viewer setting